# Conditional Broadcasting in MPI

Tags: c, mpi, broadcast

I want to write an MPI Program where each process has a boolean value `initiate` which is initially set to false. Then, rank 0 checks if the value (`i`,`j`) of a large 2D Boolean Array is true and if it is then rank 0 sets its value of `initiate` to true. If rank 0's value of `initiate` is true then I would like rank 0 to broadcast the new value of `initiate` to other processes, indirectly telling each of them to kickstart execution of another method.

How could I go about doing this efficiently? Would appreciate to hear any ideas.

-Thanks

PS. I considered sending the 2d boolean array to every process, but that 2d array can be **very** big under certain circumstances and I am worried that my code would not scale well.

Comment: the easy approach is to compute `initiate` on rank `0`, broadcast it, and then the other ranks know what to do. Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: I was hoping to broadcast only when rank 0 finds `initiate` to be true. how can I do that? Otherwise if I broadcast every time rank 0 computes the value of `initiate` that can be very expensive as rank 0 computes a value for `initiate` a bunch of times that is usually false

Comment: You can use MPI_Ibcast() and poll (e.g. MPI_Test()) on the non root ranks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to make use of the wait time. Elaborating on Gilles Gouaillardet's comment, you can build an "interrupt" kind of structure.

```
bool initiate = false;

if (rank == 0)
  for(int k = 0; k < I * J; k++)
    if(!bool_arr[k]) {
      initiate = true;
      break;
    }

MPI_Request request;
MPI_Ibcast(&initiate, 1, MPI_C_BOOL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

for (int iter = 0; iter < numiter; iter++) {

    ; // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT!

    // TEST IF THE BROADCAST COMPLETE ONCE IN A WHILE
    bool complete;
    MPI_Test(&request, &complete, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    if (complete && initiate) {
      function();
      initiate = false; // Avoid calling function() twice
    }
}
// DO NOT MOVE ON WITHOUT WAITING FOR BROADCAST
MPI_Wait(&request, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
if (initiate)
  function();
```

Comment: you need to reset `initiate=false` if invoking `function()` in the `for` loop, otherwise it gets called twice.